# Django polymorphic admin list views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a list of global configuration variables in my Django code, where some are integers, and some are strings.

I am currently using django-polymorphic, such that the base model has the name, and the child models have the values.

For example:

```py
class Configuration(PolymorphicModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ConfigurationInt(Configuration):
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} = {self.value}'


class ConfigurationStr(Configuration):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=256,default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} = {self.value}'
```

The models are then registered to the admin part like so:

```py
@admin.register(Configuration)
class ConfigurationAdmin(PolymorphicParentModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__',)
    child_models = (ConfigurationInt, ConfigurationStr)


@admin.register(ConfigurationInt)
class ConfigurationIntAdmin(PolymorphicChildModelAdmin):
    base_model = ConfigurationInt


@admin.register(ConfigurationStr)
class ConfigurationStrAdmin(PolymorphicChildModelAdmin):
    base_model = ConfigurationStr
```

Unfortunately the __str__ part only shows the base class one in the shared list view of "Configuration".
The value can't be accessible in any way that I can see, other than looking in the specific lists of "ConfigurationInt" and "ConfigurationStr".

Is there any kind of way to actually list them in one nice list?

Let's suppose I forget django-polymorphic and go with sparse data, such that each configuration has both an integer and a string, and some mechanism to state what it should be, like a type integer.
I could then show the right data in a __str__ implementation, however when editing, it will show both.
This might be ok in a simple example like this, however I have also significantly more complex models that have widely differentiating fields, but are all logically belonging to a single list.
Is there a way then in the admin interface to hide/show certain fields e.g. in list_display and list_editable, based on a field?

Long story short, is there any way to actually properly implement a polymorphic list in the admin interface?
Having it editable in the shared list view would be amazing, but even just having the information actually shown, while only being able to edit inside the objects themselves, or in the specific lists, would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Burried in the source code of `polymorphic.admin.parentadmin.py` is this:

```
    #: Whether the list should be polymorphic too, leave to ``False`` to optimize
    polymorphic_list = False

    ...

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # optimize the list display.
        qs = super(PolymorphicParentModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if not self.polymorphic_list:
            qs = qs.non_polymorphic()
        return qs
```

which kind of makes sense. Seeing as you're probably displaying 20 items there it makes sense to try and optimize it by default. Too much potential for that page to timeout otherwise.

Anyway, I think setting:

```
polymorphic_list = True
```

will hopefully fix this issue for you :)

Actually, it's in the docs too, (under implementation details):

> By default, the non_polymorphic() method will be called on the queryset, so only the Parent model will be provided to the list template. This is to avoid the performance hit of retrieving child models.
>
> This can be controlled by setting the polymorphic_list property on the parent admin. Setting it to True will provide child models to the list template.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I wanted! My data sets are pretty small, maximum in the range of tens, so I doubt performance will matter much.

Comment: Yeah, even with 20 I think it'll be fine most of the time. Glad to help :)